# What is the purpose of the AraC gene in pGLO?

Tags: microbiology, synthetic-biology

The AraC gene activates in pGLO from my understanding in the presence of arabinose. Arabinose is present as a metabolite from other metabolic in the e.coli cell. Is it that there's no termination marker, so transcription continues to the GFP gene?

In addition, does AraC contain parts that are encoded 5'->3' and 5'->3'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AraC gene can activate GFP expression, because the GFP in the pGLO plasmid has the [negative inducible pBAD promoter](https://blog.addgene.org/plasmids-101-inducible-promoters):
In the absence of arabinose an AraC protein dimer binds the promotor region, but does not activate transcription. When arabinose is present, the protein binds in a different way, which allows the downstearm gene (here GFP) to be produced.

According to [this plasmid map](https://www.novoprolabs.com/uploads/unzip/Fluorescent%20Protein%20Genes%20&%20Plasmids/pGLO%20Map.png) I found the AraC and GFP genes are in different orientations (and facing 'away' from each other), so transcription of AraC wouldn't run over into GFP even without a terminator present.